# speed up the for loop

Tags: r, loops

Here is my data.

```
set.seed(100)
toydata <- data.frame(A = sample(0:50,50,replace = T),
                  B = sample(0:50,50,replace = T),
                  C = sample(0:50,50,replace = T),
                  D = sample(0:50,50,replace = T),
                  E = sample(0:50,50,replace = T)

)
toydata<-as.matrix(toydata)
toydata[1,]<-0
toydata[44,]<-0

toydata[1,4]<-3
toydata[44,1]<-4

m<-toydata
```

Here is my swapping function:

```
derangement <- function(x){
  if(max(table(x)) > length(x)/2) return(NA)
  while(TRUE){
    y <- sample(x)
    if(all(y != x)) return(y)
  }
}

swapFun <- function(x, n = 10){
  inx <- which(x < n)
  y <- derangement(x[inx])
  if(length(y) == 1) return(NA) 
  x[inx] <- y
  x
}
```

After swapping, I want the sum of the difference of the row medians between the two matrixes are less than 12.

I use for loop to find a feasible solution:

```
for (i in 1:1000000000) {
  mnew<-swapFun(m)
  if((sum(abs(rowMedians(mnew)-rowMedians(m))))<12) 
    {break}

}
```

My computer has 5 cores. How can I speed up the for loop by using more cores.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the `foreach` and the `doParallel` package.

Comment: Use the C language inside the R

Comment: @Fernandes How can I fulfill that because I have no knowledge with C. Thanks.

Comment: an interesting post that might help with this :https://www.r-bloggers.com/implementing-mclapply-on-windows-a-primer-on-embarrassingly-parallel-computation-on-multicore-systems-with-r/